# SubjectConfirmationData missing recipient field

Tags: wso2, salesforce, wso2-identity-server

I'm still kind of new to WSO2 but have successfully setup many different applications to work with it.  I am running into an issue currently trying to connect our Salesforce instance with WSO2.  I keep getting a validation error saying "One of the SubjectConfirmationData elements is missing a recipient field"  When looking at the SAML response it is not including a recipient field at all. I'm not sure how to get it in there.

We are currently on WSO2 Carbon Version 5.1.0.   Under my service provider for Salesforce I have enabled recipient validation and added urls to that list, but it still doesn't add a recipient to the SubjectConfirmationData element.  Any ideas on what to do?

Here is the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="llikhiplnckepadmgibmamebigbbbbgfhggdbjgf" IssueInstant="2020-01-02T22:31:11.217Z" Version="2.0">
   <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">https://example.com/samlsso</saml2:Issuer>
   <saml2p:Status>
      <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
   </saml2p:Status>
   <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="elgkemhepilbljfckgfgchapaefibpocgjpbcnpn" IssueInstant="2020-01-02T22:31:11.217Z" Version="2.0">
      <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">https://example.com/samlsso</saml2:Issuer>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#elgkemhepilbljfckgfgchapaefibpocgjpbcnpn">
               <ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
               </ds:Transforms>
               <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
               <ds:DigestValue>DUTHXbKOU45H9dpv81sleR8z+UZLnNBLICiyooxph0M=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
         </ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:SignatureValue>blah blah blah</ds:SignatureValue>
         <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate>blah blah blah</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
         </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <saml2:Subject>
         <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">ktest</saml2:NameID>
         <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2020-01-02T22:36:11.217Z" />
         </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
      </saml2:Subject>
      <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2020-01-02T22:31:11.217Z" NotOnOrAfter="2020-01-02T22:36:11.217Z">
         <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml2:Audience>MySite</saml2:Audience>
            <saml2:Audience>https://saml.salesforce.com</saml2:Audience>
            <saml2:Audience>https://example.com/samlsso</saml2:Audience>
         </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
      </saml2:Conditions>
      <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2020-01-02T22:31:11.217Z">
         <saml2:AuthnContext>
            <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
         </saml2:AuthnContext>
      </saml2:AuthnStatement>
      <saml2:AttributeStatement />
   </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h25NX.png)

[SAML Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk3tn.png)

[Salesforce Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Bjk.png)

Comment: Can you please attach the saml request and response?

Comment: Just added the response.  Not sure how to get the request from Salesforce.  I am doing the test through the validator.

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot of the Service provider configs in the management console (UI)?

Comment: Just added some screenshots.  Sorry I had to block out any business-related names.